# Color of select tag

Tags: html, css, select, colors

I made a kind of placeholder in select tag, but have no clue how to change its color to grey. I need only "your location" in grey, the rest should stay black. Can it be done in pure css/html?

HTML:

```
<select>
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Your Location</option>
<option value="Warszawa">Warszawa</option>
<option value="Gdańsk">Gdańsk</option>
<option value="Kraków">Kraków</option>
```

CSS:

```
select, select option {
background-color: #f4f4f4;
margin: 5px 2px 2px 0;
padding-left: 20px;
border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
color: black;
```

}

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/LrqLthpr/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```css
.greenColor{
    background-color: #33CC33;
}
.redColor{
    background-color: #E60000;
}
```

```html
<select id="reviewAction">  
<option class="greenColor">Accept and Advance Status</option>
<option class="redColor">Return for Modifications</option>
</select>
```

or

```css
.Color{
    background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<select id="reviewAction">  
<option class="Color">Accept and Advance Status</option>
<option class="Color">Return for Modifications</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you changed an option background, and i need the font color of "your location", which is not even shown in dropdown to be gray

Answer (score 0):

Do You want the selected option with other color or the first option??

If you want the selected option, you can try this:

select option[selected]{
}

If you want just the first option:

select option:first{
}

Comment: I need a selected "your location" to be gray, to work like a placeholder. Anything that is selected or in dropdown should stay black.

Comment: Add a class to it and create a CSS applying the color gray.